не приходят письма подтверждения аккаунта Firebase на mail.ru
Для подтверждения аккаунта в Firebase,  созданного с помощью почты и пароля, необходимо получить письмо с подтверждением от FB. По каким-то причинам, письма не приходят на ящики mail.ru? При этом на yandex.ru приходят. Есть идеи что это может быть и можно ли как-то исправить?

есть идея: надо написать в техподдержку.

проверьте спам как вариант...

Краткий ответ ТП mail.ru:
"Проверьте настройки в разделе «Фильтры»:
Если фильтр не виноват и писем в папке «Спам» нет, обратитесь в службу поддержки Firebase и запросите:
полный текст отчёта о недоставке письма;
полный лог SMTP-сессии отправки письма почтовым сервером отправителя на ваш адрес."
Не знаю как долго такого ждать от Гугла, даже не стал смотреть куда писать.
Есть простой выход. В настройках аутентификации Firebase есть возможность сделать отправку через свой SMTP. Настроил через mail.ru теперь всё ок.
